# Rank as norm on matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, metric-spaces, normed-spaces, noncommutative-algebra

Could we consider matrix rank $r$ a norm?

Is other norm similar to rank $r$ possible to associate with a finite matrix?

(We denote trivial valuation $|\alpha|=1,\quad\forall\alpha\in\Bbb F^*$ where $\Bbb F$ is field/division algebra).

It seems to satisfy norm axioms:

$1$ $\mathsf{rank}(M)=0\iff M=0$.

$2$ $\mathsf{rank}(\alpha M)=|\alpha|\mathsf{rank}(M)=\mathsf{rank}(M)$.

$3$ $\mathsf{rank}(M+N)\leq \mathsf{rank}(M)+\mathsf{rank}(N)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

In fact, the theory of of [rank error correcting codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_error-correcting_code) makes use of this observation:
The rank provides an absolute value of the set of all $m\times n$-matrices. Hence $d(A,B) = \operatorname{rk}(A - B)$ is a metric.

Comment: So metric space comes only from norms. What I mean is if you have a metric space you need to have a norm?

Comment: Also that is over $\mathsf{GF}$. What about $\mathsf{char}(\Bbb F)=0$ cases along with division algebra cases?

Comment: Turbo: No, not all metric spaces come from norms. For any field (infinite or not) the rank provides an absolute value and $d$ is a metric.

Comment: thank you. Could you give me an example metric spaces not coming from norms? So here rank is a norm which also yields a metric?

Comment: Yes. it is very useful. It does not address skew-fields though.

Comment: Turbo: Should be true for skewfields,too.

Comment: Hmmm do you have a proof?

Comment: Turbo: Just take the standard linear algebra proof. Works also for skewfields.